Firebase not working on my website when opening from mobile devices
in my website Signup page,
i'm using firebase auth for web ( @angular/fire version for angular websites ) to signup a user using Google Signup, i'm doing this using the SignInWithPopup function.
this is my AuthService class :
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  private readonly api_url: string = environment.apiUrl

  async googleAuth() {
    return await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(new GoogleAuthProvider())
  }

  etc ...

and using it like this in signup.component.ts :
  googleUserSubmitted() {

    this.loadingGoogleUser = true

    this.signupWithGoogle()
      .then((res) => {

        res.user?.getIdToken()
          .then((token) => {

            this.googleForm.patchValue({
              email: res.user?.email,
              name: res.user?.displayName,
              tokenID: token
            })

          })
          .finally(() => {
            this.loadingGoogleUser = false
          })

      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.loadingGoogleUser = false
      })
}


this function works normally on my laptop when using chrome or firefox browser .
but the problem when i try to signup form my android device, I've inspected the console using USB debugging to see what errors I'm getting when doing so. and I saw the following :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getProjectConfig?key=MY_API_KEY_HERE' from origin 'https://sakostore-bd7ad.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

what I tried to solve this problem and sadly not working :

I've tried Huawei and Samsung mobile devices the problem is the same
I've checked the Authorized Domains in Firebase Console and its listed correctly
I've allowed third party cookies and popups

some context to help you understand the problem :

this is the domain of the website http://77.37.125.123/ ( note there is no SSL applied )
I'm using Hostinger VPS, with nginx, This is the config file : click here to see the file


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are you using SigninWithPopup or SigninWithRedirect? Previously I had same issue and I started using SigninWithRedirect

I Considered the SingInWithRedirect Option , but i need the idToken of the user to verify it by the backend ( Nestjs using firebase/auth ), and get user claims like its avatar and name to store them in my database ( i'm using firebase authenticating just for auth not storing users data )

I Found The Solution Finally  .
i forgot to try to connect to a VPN.
while living in syria there are some restrictions when connecting the website with the firebase web app instance.
my mobile devices was not connected to any vpn . so GoolgeAuthProvider() neither any firebase service was not working .
it appeared to be a region problem
